# Optimizing Spark/Scala speed

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, apache-spark, optimization

I have a Spark script that establishes a connection to Hive and read Data from different databases and then writes the union into a CSV file. I tested it with two databases and it took 20 minutes. Now I am trying it with 11 databases and it has been running since yesterday evening (18 hours!). The script is supposed to get between 400000 and 800000 row per database.

My question is: is 18 hours normal for such jobs? If not, how can I optimize it? This is what my main does:

```
// This is a list of the ten first databases used:
var use_database_sigma = List( Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGca, Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGcm
                                  ,Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGge, Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGne
                                  ,Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGoc, Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGoi
                                  ,Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGra, Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaGsu
                                  ,Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaPvl, Parametre_vigiliste.sourceDbSigmaLbr)


    val grc = Tables.getGRC(spark) // This creates the first dataframe

    var sigma = Tables.getSIGMA(spark, use_database_sigma(0)) // This creates other dataframe which is the union of ten dataframes (one database each)
    for(i <- 1 until use_database_sigma.length)
    {
    if (use_database_sigma(i) != "")
     {
        sigma = sigma.union(Tables.getSIGMA(spark, use_database_sigma(i)))
      }
    }

// writing into csv file

    val grc_sigma=sigma.union(grc) // union of the 2 dataframes
    grc_sigma.cache
    LogDev.ecrireligne("total : " + grc_sigma.count())
    grc_sigma.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|").save(Parametre_vigiliste.cible)
    val conf = new Configuration()
    val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
    val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/part*"))(0).getPath().getName();
        fs.rename(new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/" + file), new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/" + "FIC_PER_DATALAKE_.csv"));
  grc_sigma.unpersist()
```

Comment: I'd cache the dataframes before union and repartition to make sure the data is available to the cluster in an efficient fashion. You never know if there are pushdowns and what not going on. Try to do an .explain and see the execution plan.

Comment: At what level do you think is best to cache the DF? For GRC it is easy. But for sigma should I execute sigma.cache() inside the loop after each union?

Comment: I'd cache them all before the union. Loop through them and return an array of cached dataframes, then .reduce('underscore'.unionByName('underscore')) the array and write out the resulting dataframe to csv. EDIT: underscores are apparently trimmed in comments.

Comment: Can you please write it on an answer so I can check? Thank you again

Comment: Hi, I think that you can improve it by mofiying your application architecture.
Instead of using var, in a for loop, wth an if in it, you can redesign it using map.
Since, use_database_sigma is a list, mapping over it is not very complicated, and for each element, you can apply the filter instead of if. I think that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not written in an IDE so it might be off somewhere, but you get the general idea.

```
val frames = Seq("table1", "table2).map{ table =>
   spark.read.table(table).cache()
}

frames
.reduce(_.union(_)) //or unionByName() if the columns aren't in the same order
.repartition(1)
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format("csv")
.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> "|"))
.save("filePathName")
```

Comment: i actually manipulate Dataframes. Can I replace table1 by name of df ?

Comment: Yes, just omit the read.table part and call cache on them. See if that helps. Though I missed you already had your data in Hive, I thought it was regular SQL databases. I think you have some other problem if it takes 18 hours to union and repartition around 10 million rows. That should be a walk in the park under normal circumstances.